# Access System Tray Icons Balloon Text

Tags: windows, powershell, balloon-tip

I know how to create an icon for the system tray that displays different balloon text depending on conditions. What I'm looking for is the ability to read an icons current set balloon text.

IE:  You hover over your network icon and get basic info.

Can PowerShell access this information, without moving the cursor over the item?

Comment: No, that would be accessing process memory information and without knowing what you're looking for, I'm unsure it is possible *trivially*.